# why windows key is not working inside vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was hoping.. could anybody help me about this matter?

I am using this [better jest](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoachRichbart.better-jest&ssr=false) extension on visual studio code. 
there are shortcut keys like:
`windows + k + r`

but when I press `windows key` it doesn't work inside the editor.

rather it works outside.

I have tried everything but couldn't find any solution.
is there any fix for this?

Comment: where in the extension is the windows key named, Nowhere

Comment: in the keyboard shortcuts, it is named as `Windows`. i have to press `Windows + K Windows + R` like this to activate the respective action

Comment: @rioV8 you can see the extension here https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CoachRichbart.better-jest&ssr=false
after installing it in windows (vscode), these cmd key (command) gets changed into windows key

Comment: As a side note, using the Windows key for this is probably not a great idea. Over the last few Windows releases, Microsoft have been adding more and more native hotkeys there, and if they add something for Windows+K, it will take precedence over anything you've bound in an app. I've had Windows+V bound to [PureText](https://stevemiller.net/puretext/) for about 20 years, but it recently stopped working because it now launches Windows Clipboard History.

Comment: Note that it's not supposed to be Win+K+R but Win+K Win+R

Comment: i tried all of those.. but it doesn't work inside vscode.. instead it works these defaults by windows operating system...  Windows + R :Run a command.. Windows + K :Connect to wireless displays and audio devices

Comment: when i press these keys in any ways.. everything works on outside vscode like windows + k.. it shows pop ups on right side of my screen.. (not inside vscode editor)

Comment: filed an issue: https://github.com/CoachRichbart/better-jest/issues/3

Comment: you can change the `package.json` file of the extension until the fix is implemented in a new update.

Comment: thank you @rioV8 this doesn't occurred to me.. contacting the one who created the extension

Comment: looks like the extension is not maintained any more, you can copy the repo as an extension and change the keybindings in package.json, remove the installed `better jest` first

Answer (score -1):

Change the `package.json` file of the extension:

```
        "keybindings": [
            {
                "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+r",
                "command": "better-jest.run",
                "when": "editorLangId == javascript || editorLangId == typescript"
            },
            {
                "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+f",
                "command": "better-jest.run-file",
                "when": "editorLangId == javascript || editorLangId == typescript"
            },
            {
                "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+p",
                "command": "better-jest.run-previous",
                "when": "editorLangId == javascript || editorLangId == typescript"
            }
```

Comment: sorry.. i have other important shortcuts with these keys.. i really needed the windows key to work

Comment: @MegaBang Windows key is not supported as modifier key in VSC, choose a different prefix instead of Ctrl+k and define these bindings in `keybindings.json`

Comment: @MegaBang I tried on Windows to define a key binding with `Windows+K` but it shows me the **Devices** selection on the right of the Desktop.